# Unable to call extension method with null-object

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm trying to parse XML attributes out of a XmlDocument. Since it's possible, that a certain node does not have a specific attribute, I've created an extension method to check the attribute and return a default value if the attribute is null or invalid:

```
public static bool TryParseOrDefault(this string toParse, bool defaultValue)
 {
   if(toParse == null) return defaultValue;
   bool result;
   if(Boolean.TryParse(toParse, out result))
   {
        return result;
   }
   return defaultValue;
 }
```

This works well enough, however it does not when the object I want to check is null:

```
var whatever = column.Attributes["SomeAttribute"].Value.TryParseOrDefault(true);
```

In this case the `column` node doesn't have the `SomeAttribute` attribute, thus `Value` is null and a `NullReferenceException` is thrown. Why is that? I thought extension methods are supposed to work on null objects, since the call basically translates to this:

```
MyExtensions.TryParseOrDefault(column.Attributes["SomeAttribute"].Value,true);
```

Comment: I've tried your code with `String St = null; St.TryParseOrDefault(true);` it does work OK.

Comment: If you don't have `SomeAttribute` then `Attributes["SomeAttribute"]` will return null. so basically you're trying to access `null.Value` is where you get an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that if `Attributes["SomeAttribute"]` return null - so finding the `Value` property will fail. If `column` is an `XmlElement`, that would certainly be the case - look at the [`XmlAttributeCollection.ItemOf(string)` property (the indexer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1b823yx9.aspx):

> **Property value**
>   The XmlAttribute with the specified name. If the attribute does not exist, this property returns null.

You're right about the translation of the extension method - but I don't think that's the problem. It's easy to test that though - just split the statement up for diagnostic purposes:

```
string tmp = column.Attributes["SomeAttribute"].Value;
var whatever = tmp.TryParseOrDefault(true);
```

I suspect you'll find the exception is on the *first* line, not the second.

You may wish to consider using LINQ to XML, which makes this easier - there you could use:

```
string tmp = (string) column.Attribute("SomeAttribute");
```

and that *will* return `null` if the attribute is missing, because the explicit conversion from `XAttribute` to `string` will return `null` if the "source" of the conversion is a null reference.

(If you *only* need this for `XmlAttribute`, then Rune's answer is a great one too. It depends on what you're trying to do.)

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I'm now doing a null check on the Attributes property before and now take a look at your LINQ to XML suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the `.Value` that's `null` but the attribute ans you are therefore effectively doing this `null.Value` which throws the mentioned exception. You could change the extension method to accept a `XAttribute` instead of a string

```
public static bool TryParseOrDefault(this XAttribute toParse, bool defaultValue)
 {
   if(toParse == null) return defaultValue;
   bool result;
   if(Boolean.TryParse(toParse.Value, out result))
   {
        return result;
   }
   return defaultValue;
 }
```

and then call it like this

```
var whatever = column.Attributes["SomeAttribute"].TryParseOrDefault(true);
```

you could also create an override to the LINQ2XML extension method

```
public static bool Attribute(this XElement elem, string attributeName, bool defaultValue)
 {
   var toParse = (string)elem.Attribute(attributeName);
   bool result;
   if(Boolean.TryParse(toParse, out result))
   {
        return result;
   }
   return defaultValue;
 }
```

which you'd then use like this:

```
var whatever = column.Attribute("SomeAttribute",true);
```

Comment: Nice and useful answer.